# Gas Furnace and Water Softener Drain Lines Configuration

Tags: furnace, drainage, water-softener

Just wondering if anyone can explain why the drain lines out of the furnace has a loop before entering the sewer drain. As well as the drain line for the water softener being elevated above the softener system.  I assume both of these have to do with trapping water? Asking incase it should be a straight run to avoid water sitting in the plastic tube on both devices.

Furnace Model York Affinity YP9C

[image: Back of Furnace]

[image: Water Softener 1]

[image: Water Softener 2]

Comment: Pictures of these drains, as well as the make/model of the furnace would help.

Comment: I tried to upload yesterday but got a server error. They seem to uploaded now.

Comment: I'm no expert, but that loop on the furnace looked like someone had screws & zip ties, but nothing to cut the hose with. That looks really wrong to me. Not sure about what the issue is with the softener. Maybe a pic with an arrow pointing to what the problem area is?